# SQL database not connecting to Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2015

I have downloaded and installed Visual Studio 2015 Community (because it is being used in college professional version) and SQL Server 2016 Service Pack 3 with SQL Server Management Studio 18.

I have been trying to connect or create a new database connection and it is showing me the attached error

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies.

I have tried multiple solutions here and it took me a whole day and it's still not fixed.

I have downloaded all SQL Server features from feature pack found from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=103444

Installed packages via nupkg still no success.

Also, I checked the `C:/Program Data/assembly` and it contained the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc` version 13.0.0.0
while it gives the error of 12.0.0.0.

I need help!

PS: I had previously installed 2019 version but uninstalled it and all of it's components (I think all) is it the issue? if that is recommend something to solve this issue, I have a project to show on Monday.

Comment: Are you getting the error only with Visual Studio IDE database functionality? If so, it's like a problem with the VS install. If SSMS is working, use that to create databases, objects, etc. and VS for the C# app. That may be easiest to meet your deadline.

Comment: Are you running the latest build of SSMS? I suggest you uninstall and reinstall SSMS

Comment: That's the feature pack, not SQL Server Express. Try the following: [Download SQL Server Express 2016 w/SP3](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=799012) For SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) see the following: [Download SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: The following may be helpful as well: https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-download-and-install-sql-server-2016-express-edition/

Comment: Dan Guzman, Yes, only from Visual studio

Comment: Charlieface, I have uninstalled everything, trying to reinstall. How to completely remove everything as maybe the system files might be there from the previous versions I had tried?

Answer (score 1):

Please try download and install Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types and Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Shared Management Objects from :
https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=42295

In addition, which version of your Windows? If you are using Windows 10, SQL Server 2012 requires service pack 2 to make it compatible with Windows 10. Please download and install from below link.
[http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43351](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=42295)

Comment: I have downloaded and installed CLR types and shared management objects still no luck. I am using WIndows 10. and the SQL Server is 2016 not 2012